# Browser and version detection

Tags: javascript

Based off of [another SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript) by kennebec, I had problems following the code so I rewrote it to give myself a better understanding of what is being accomplished.

I would be very grateful if you could critique it or point out any problems I have caused or could modify to improve it.

Tested with IE8/9/10/11, FF, Chrome, Opera & Safari.

Original [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wzh5apg2/22/)
Updated with changes from thriggle [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wzh5apg2/31/)

```
function getBrowser() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent, 
        matched = userAgent.match(/(chrome|firefox|opera|safari|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [],
        version,
        browser = { name: '', version: '' };

    // IE Shells; I gaurantee that you will see this with Dell branded OEM IE 11 installs.
    if(/trident/i.test(matched[1])) { 
        version = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(userAgent) || [];        

        return { name: 'Internet Explorer', version: (version[1] || '') };
    }

    // Not Chrome; at first glance this looks like a block for chrome identification, but 
    // its actually Opera.
    if(matched[1] === 'Chrome') {
        version = userAgent.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);

        if(version !== null) {
            return { name: version[1].replace('OPR', 'Opera'), version: version[2] };
        }
    }

    // The rest; Chrome, Safari, etc
    matched = matched[2] ? [matched[1], matched[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];

    if((version = userAgent.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) !== null) {
        matched.splice(1, 1, version[1]);
    }

    browser.name = (matched[0] !== "") ? matched[0] : "Unknown";
    browser.version = (matched[1] !== "") ? matched[1] : "Unknown"; 

    return browser;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Kennebec's original answer, the code is inconsistent in its identification of different versions of browsers. For example, Internet Explorer 9 will appear as `MSIE 9.0` while Internet Explorer 11 (which despite forsaking the family name still wields the trident of its ancestors) will appear as `Internet Explorer 11`. Since you have direct control over the name returned for a trident-detected version of IE, why not return "MSIE" instead of "Internet Explorer"?

Super minor nitpick: you misspelled "guarantee" in the code comments.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have updated the fiddle(now v31) with your point of inconsistency and it is an improvement.